# How to create user with password, drop roles and database with ownership in yugabyte db?

Tags: yugabytedb

Objective: To create user with password, drop roles and database with ownership in yugabyte

Commands Executed:

```
cd /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-1.3.0.0/bin
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres -W
\i /index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql
```

Logs:

```
postgres=# \i /index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.2.24, server 11.2)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 11.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
psql:/index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql:9: ERROR:  database "yugastore" does not exist
psql:/index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql:11: ERROR:  DROP USER not supported yet
LINE 1: DROP USER ydba;
        ^
HINT:  See https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues/869. Click '+' on the description to raise its priority
psql:/index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql:13: ERROR:  CREATE USER ROLE with element not supported yet
LINE 1: CREATE USER ydba WITH PASSWORD 'ydba123';
                              ^
HINT:  See https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues/869. Click '+' on the description to raise its priority
psql:/index/yugabyte/yugastore.sql:15: ERROR:  role "ydba" does not exist
```

Please help me in resolving the issues!

Comment: You have a very old version of YugabyteDB. Try with 2.0.10 and reply. Those features weren't supported in that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](https://download.yugabyte.com/) the db:

```
wget https://downloads.yugabyte.com/yugabyte-2.0.10.0-linux.tar.gz
tar xvfz yugabyte-2.0.10.0-linux.tar.gz && cd yugabyte-2.0.10.0/
./bin/post_install.sh
./bin/yb-ctl create
./bin/ysqlsh
```

Sql code:

```
yugabyte=# create database ydb;
CREATE DATABASE
yugabyte=# create user ydba WITH PASSWORD 'ydba123';
CREATE ROLE
yugabyte=# ALTER DATABASE ydb OWNER TO ydba;
ALTER DATABASE
yugabyte=# drop user ydba;
ERROR:  role "ydba" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of database ydb
yugabyte=# drop database ydb;
DROP DATABASE
yugabyte=# drop user ydba;
DROP ROLE
yugabyte=#
```